# How to hand-in an Xcode project in a wise way?

Tags: ios

well, I have my Xcode project done recently, which is a "promising" iOS app, and need to be evaluated by my boss in order to apply for a development group. But, no wonder, bosses are always, u know, lack of "professional" skills. I even cannot assume them to have an xcode compiler on his computer.

But, I need to present what I have done in a intuitive way. I have already finished a "project report", and I have to hand them in together with my project codes. well, that's the rule, and I cannot stay with my bosses to explain "how to open the file"..

So, I am wondering if there is a more simple way to show them the app. luckily, I can burn a CD to store the things they need. However, obviously, I rank "give them a Xcode install file" as the least choice.

Is there any better way that I can show my work? i.e. provide an iOS Simulator with that app pre installed? how could that happen? or any way else?

by the way, I have tried to upload it on App Store, but failed. Since it is just a raw beta version (too ugly to be listed on Store, as Apple explained). And I have heard that I can use "Enterprise Distribution" to skip App Store check. But, I cannot have an "Enterprise license".

Comment: [App Distribution Guide: Beta Testing your iOS App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

Comment: Distribute the IPA as esqew said... details are in the link. -- the other party **needs** an iphone/ipod/ipad though

Comment: Thank you sir, but do I need any special "license" or "certificates" for doing this beta distribution? I am now a apple developer. and Surely, I dont think I can know my boss's iPhone unique ID to add them as my tester....

Comment: Ad hoc app distributions are a pain in the ass.  If your requirement is "zero effort from my boss" then it probably won't work for you.  Instead, give him a device with the app on it.  If that doesn't work, give him a laptop with the app on it.  Ideally you could get some time on their calendar to present it.  Alternatively, you can provide the code on github and maybe record some videos that walk them through the app.

Comment: I would buy an iPod touch and give him that with the app on it. (Provided it doesn't need cellular data)